# How to restore Recent Files?

Tags: windows, file-recovery

I accidentally cleared all the list in the folder "recent files." 
Is there a way to get it back?

For example, if I did a System Restore, would it help me in this case?

I have Windows 7.

Comment: “Is there a way to get it back?” - No, You deleted the file.  “if I did a System Restore, would it help me in this case?” - It’s possible.

Answer (score 0):

Recent Places is located in the `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent` folder in each user's profile and contains system-generated shortcuts (.LNK files) to recently opened items. There's nothing special about these files, therefore they can be recovered in the same way other files would be.  Here are some suggestions:

1. Undo last action with Ctrl+Z (only works if last action was to delete the files)
2. Recycle Bin
3. Previous Versions
4. Restore from backup
5. System Restore
6. File recovery tools

Comment: While I agree there is nothing special about the files the method used to delete them (CCcleaner) means they weren’t not sent to the recycle bin (even if they were it was likely emptied).  Typically the folder in question doesn’t keep a file history by default.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm being thorough by including all possible recovery options (The next person may not be aware the Recycle Bin would actually be an option). Before posting I confirmed Recent Items folder is protected by Previous Versions on Windows 7.